# How to run snmpwalk using linux script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, snmp

Basically i am new in the field of shell scripting and i want to run snmpwalk using linux script

**here is the script i have created:**

```
echo "Starting SnmpWalk"

 var = `snmpwalk -v2c CS IP 1.3.6.1.4.1.1563.10.1.4.2.1.1.1.1.7`
 
 echo {var}
```

**(I have entered the community String and Ip Correct.)**

but i am getting a error as :

```
Starting SnmpWalk
No community name specified.
USAGE: snmpwalk [OPTIONS] AGENT [OID]
  Version:  5.9.1
  Web:      http://www.net-snmp.org/
  Email:    net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net
```

Comment: Please include the command you use to run this script. When you run it you will get errors and unexpected output; you should include those here too. Have you tried to fix the errors? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You may be assuming that `-v2c` on your command line means `-v2` + `-c`, i.e. the options to specify SNMP version 2 and the community name.

Unfortunately, that is not correct: if you check `man snmpcmd` (= the man page that lists all the options that are shared by most Net-SNMP tools), it says this on option `-v`:

> ```
> -v 1 | 2c | 3
> ```
>
> Specifies the protocol version to use: 1 (RFCs 1155-1157), 2c (RFCs 1901-1908), or 3 (RFCs 2571-2574). [...]

So, `-v2c` only specifies the SNMP protocol version **2c**, and you need a separate option `-c` to specify the community string, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting SnmpWalk"
var=$(snmpwalk -v2c -c "CS" IP 1.3.6.1.4.1.1563.10.1.4.2.1.1.1.1.7)
echo "$var"
```

(It's better to use the `$(`...`)` construct instead of backticks, and if your community string contains any special characters, it needs to be quoted. Assignments must not contain spaces. Also, the result variable `var`'s value may contain spaces, semicolons or other characters that have a special meaning to the shell, so it'll be safer to use quotes when using the value of the variable, to avoid accidentally attempting to execute parts of the value as a command.)